# How to prevent python from trying to load `/home/lib/python311.zip` on startup?

Tags: python, linux, miniconda

I am installing Python via miniconda on a server I do not have root access to. Unfortunately, my home directory is mounted in an nfs, and due to a misconfiguration, accessing /home/lib is very slow (it tries to reach another server instead). When I try to start Python from the directory `/home/user/miniconda3`, it always searches for `/home/lib/python311.zip`, which takes very long because of the server's misconfiguration. See the output of `strace -f ./bin/python3/:

```
stat("/home/user/miniconda3/bin/lib/python311.zip", 0x7ffeac2109d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python311.zip", 0x7ffeac2109d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/user/lib/python311.zip", 0x7ffeac2109d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/lib/python311.zip", 0x7ffeac2109d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python311.zip", 0x7ffeac210450) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python311.zip", 0x7ffeac210720) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

What exactly is Python trying to load here? And can I prevent it from loading by adjusting the search path somehow?

Comment: Can you show the output of `import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_paths())`? What happens if you start Python with `-S`?

Comment: It's referenced [here in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys_path_init.html), and I assume it's implying that the OS independent modules might be located in such a file rather than as loose files on disk. Why is `/home/lib/` so slow if `/home/user/`/`/home/vincent/` isn't?

Comment: Because `/home` is an NFS directory - and it tries contacting another server (`lib.hostname` sort of) when searching in this directory.

Comment: @wim It seems to have the same problem when running with -S. Because of this delay, I cannot run the desired line in python.

Comment: Maybe you could put an empty `python311.zip` in one of the earlier paths so it's found and doesn't continue searching?

Comment: @MarkRansom An empty .zip won't stop it statting around

Comment: @cryptobeginner In that case, can you put the output of `python -m sysconfig`